# AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'get' (python 2.7.5)

Tags: python, pygame

I am starting to make a game but when i try to start it i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\justy\OneDrive\Documents\Programs\Parkour\parkour.py", line 25, in <module>
    Player=classPlayer(player_img,place,velocity)
  File "C:\Users\justy\OneDrive\Documents\Programs\Parkour\parkour.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.rect=self.image.get.rect()                                                                  
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Here is the full code:

```
import pygame,sys
from random import *
pygame.init()


class classPlayer(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,player_img,place,velocity):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image=pygame.image.load(player_img)
        self.rect=self.image.get.rect()             #error
        self.rect.left,self.rect.top=place
        self.velocity=velocity
    def move(self):
        self.rect=self.rect.move(self.velocity) 
        if self.rect.bottom==400:
            self.velocity[0]=self.velocity[0]-self.velocity[0]
screen=pygame.display.set_mode([700,400])
screen.fill([255,255,255])
pygame.display.flip()
            
jump=True
velocity=0.0
place=[450,900]
On=True
player_img='player.png'
Player=classPlayer(player_img,place,velocity)       #error
groupPlayer=classPlayer(Player)
while On:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
               On=False
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_SPACE and jump==True:
               velocity=2.0
               jump=False
               pygame.time.delay(1500)
               for G in range(10):
                    pygame.time.delay(50)
                    velocity = velocity - 0.4001
    pygame.time.delay(20)
    screen.fill([255,255,255])
    Player.move()
    screen.blit(Player.image,Player.rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
       
pygame.quit()
```

Can someone help?

Comment: `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()`

Comment: It's a typo `self.image.get.rect()` -> `self.image.get_rect()`

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your application: `self.image.get.rect()` must be `self.image.get_rect()`:

<s>`self.rect=self.image.get.rect()`</s>

```py
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```